# Python md5 returns wrong hexdigest

Tags: python, md5

My code:

```
filename = filename.strip().replace(' ', '_')
filename = urllib.quote(filename.encode('utf-8')).strip()
print filename
filenameHash = hashlib.md5(filename).hexdigest()
print filenameHash
```

Printed filenameHash: `5e6243a3a207220e4e386fcde5191697`

but should be `4a8ce85f21814d6d0010a3bc5bf4f82d`

Filename printed: `Gda%C5%84sk_%E2%80%93_Strefa_Historyczna_Wolnego_Miasta_Gda%C5%84ska_%28D%C5%82ugi_Targ%29.JPG`

What's wrong?

Comment: I got the `5e62...` md5 hash; how do you calculate the other one?

Comment: Why do you feel the hash is wrong? Are you certain the hash is not of the file **contents** and not the filename?

Comment: I used http://www.md5.cz/ to check

Comment: @latata: and what makes you think that that form is correct? Most likely that form decoded the encoding you put on the filename..

Comment: That page does not work if there is `%` in the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page you tested your MD5 against is incorrectly decoding your data *twice*:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> filename = 'Gda%C5%84sk_%E2%80%93_Strefa_Historyczna_Wolnego_Miasta_Gda%C5%84ska_%28D%C5%82ugi_Targ%29.JPG'
>>> hashlib.md5(filename).hexdigest()
'5e6243a3a207220e4e386fcde5191697'
>>> hashlib.md5(urllib.unquote(filename)).hexdigest()
'4a8ce85f21814d6d0010a3bc5bf4f82d'
```

Put your trust in the Python module more than a random online webpage.

If, on the other hand you meant to test the MD5 hash of just the UTF-8 encoding of the filename, then don't apply `urllib.quote()`, and the webpage inadvertently exposed an error in your approach.

Comment: That strange - it's wikipedia file and wikipedia encode urls with two first chars from md5. And for that file it's "4a" so I thought it's correct :)

Comment: Check this out: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Gda%C5%84sk_%E2%80%93_Strefa_Historyczna_Wolnego_Miasta_Gda%C5%84ska_%28D%C5%82ugi_Targ%29.JPG

Comment: @latata: So Wikimedia uses the unquoted UTF-8 encoded filename. You were using the URL-percent-encoded version.